# How to get the value of a particular textView inside ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

In my application I need to move from one activity to another depending on the list clicked. In each listview there will be three textview namely: Emp_id, Emp_name,Emp_address, so whenever I click on a particular list that should move to next activity of the corresponding Emp_id. So here I want to catch the Emp_id, which I am unable. I have tried a lot but got only the first Emp_id not the list that I have clicked.

CODE:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try{
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(Mydetail);
            JSONArray data = jObj.getJSONArray("mydata");

            for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){                       
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = data.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("Eid", "" + e.getString("E_id"));
                map.put("Ename", "" + e.getString("E_name"));
                map.put("Eaddress", "" + e.getString("E_address"));
                mylist2.add(map);
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

         ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist2 , R.layout.datalist,
                                  new String[] { "Eid", "Ename", "Eaddress" }, 
                                  new int[] {  R.id.TextView1,R.id.TextView2e,R.id.TextView3 });
                                  setListAdapter(adapter);


        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                //String val = o.get("id");

                Pnm = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
                 String str = ((TextView)Pnm).getText().toString();


                Toast.makeText(projects.this, str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent newActivitySecond = new Intent(projects.this, modules.class);     
                projects.this.startActivity(newActivitySecond);


            }
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 ListView lv_ArchivePartylist;

    lv_ArchivePartylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.archive_ListView01);
            lv_ArchivePartylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String message = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_box1).getText().toString;
                    Toast.makeText(Activityname.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) mylist2.get(position);                   

             String Emp_id = o.get("Eid");
             //use this Emp_id


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use set onclicklistener to all elements inside ListView. I have created a listview. set an adapter to the listview. My adapter is reponsible to show each element of the listview. so inside getView() I will assign onclicklistener to all the elements to whom i want to get the click event

### Example

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        holder.text.setText("item "+position);
        holder.image.setTag(data.get(position));
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.text.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position), activity, holder.image);
        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("...clicked view is...."+arg0);
    }
```

Comment: I have provided the code (above) that I am actually using now, so modifying the present code can I fix it.